# AWS credentials file in Node app, works on dev but not on local

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am using the same credential keys (as in `~/.aws/credentials`) as the dev server (where it works) but locally I get the following error:

`{ [InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.]
  message: 'The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.',
  code: 'InvalidAccessKeyId',
  region: null`

Any ideas where I can double check or a possible problem area?

Comment: can you update the question to include the basic format / content of your credentials file, and the code that is using the credentials from that file?

Comment: @DerickBailey I updated the question, after managing to catch the error

Comment: i'd still like to see a well formatted version of your credentials file (omitting the actual keys, of course) and the code used to load the credentials

Answer (score 0):

Actually almost all node stack implement dynamic configuration for your environment. Error would be most likely that in different environments you have different credentials.

Comment: The whole team is using the same credentials as well as the servers. In this format: ```[default]
aws_access_key_id = <key>
aws_secret_access_key = <key>```